# Swapping Str to Datetime in a CSV (Python)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, numpy, datetime

I have a data set named aero
I am trying to change the string dates in a given column to datetime
This is the format of the strings:

```
In: aero['Date Local'].unique()
Out: array(['2000-01-01', '2000-01-02', '2000-01-03', ..., '2016-03-04',
   '2016-03-05', '2016-03-06'], dtype=object)
```

So correct me if I'm wrong, but that looks like a mutable list of strings
here is the code I tried:

```
for stuff in aero['Date Local']:
aero['Date Local'][stuff] = datetime.datetime.strptime(stuff, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

which yielded the error:

```
ValueError: ['2' '0' '0' '0' '-' '0' '1' '-' '0' '1'] not contained in the index
```

I've tried figuring out what that means, but to no avail. Could someone help me help me switch these strings to datetimes?

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a new variable `stuff` each iteration of your loop. That's not what you want. You can just use `astype` to convert your array to `datetime`:

```
A = np.array(['2000-01-01', '2000-01-02', '2000-01-03', '2016-03-04',
              '2016-03-05', '2016-03-06'], dtype=object)

res = A.astype('datetime64[ns]')

print(res)

array(['2000-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2000-01-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2000-01-03T00:00:00.000000000', '2016-03-04T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2016-03-05T00:00:00.000000000', '2016-03-06T00:00:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Equivalently, if you have Pandas you can use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
import pandas as pd

res = pd.to_datetime(A).values  # .values extracts NumPy array
```

Therefore, assuming `aero` is a Pandas dataframe, you can use:

```
aero['Date Local'] = pd.to_datetime(aero['Date Local'])
```